# Our developers are getting below error for "PGA aggregate limit" only for xml datatype

Tags: oracle

Below is the error stack. I have tried increasing PGA aggregate limit but no luck.
it is only happening with xml datatype.

```
==================================================================================================================================================================================================================
driver stacktrace:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 79.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 79.0 (TID 1731, w3.cdhnode1.modak.com, executor 33):  
java.sql.SQLException:  
ORA-00039: error during periodic action
ORA-04036: PGA memory used by the instance exceeds PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 138

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1066)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3716)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:1015)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:979)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:579)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:352)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:338)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:624)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:295)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:266)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
```

Comment: The answer will depend on the relevant SQL and what it's doing and the size of the XMLs. You may be able to find the SQL with a query like this: `select * from gv$active_session_history order by pga_allocated desc;`

Comment: our developers are doing profiling and the size of it is 1GB.
any suggestions here are welcomed.

Comment: I think that LOBs and XML are always read into memory. If your XML files are 1GB you'll need at least 1GB set for the parameter `pga_aggregate_limit`. If the parameter is higher than 1GB, then make sure the program handles XML rows one-at-a-time.