# Out of Process memory issue with below error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Previously i was getting PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT exceeded issue. so i have changed PGA_AGGRIGATE_LIMIT to 0(no limit).

We have 47GB RAM. we have set PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT=0. and PGA_TARGET=10GB. still getting "OUT OF PROCESS MEMORY ISSUE" any suggestions here will be appreciated.

Below is Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 107096 bytes (kolarsCreateCt,qmemNextBuf:Large Alloc)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 138.

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1066)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3716)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many things that could affect this situation and cause this error, including your PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT, your OS and kernel configuration, ulimit settings for the oracle user (on Linux), etc. If you should have plenty of physical RAM, then I suspect ulimit values may be your problem - artificially limiting the amount of memory the OS can allocate. See these links for additional troubleshooting tips:

- https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=error-message-ora-04030
- https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=454361477893454&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=HOWTO&id=1934141.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=2l47phfis_4
- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_04030_out_process_memory.htm

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64209588/409172), and that you are loading large XML files that are using up all of the memory. Adjusting the memory settings like pmdba suggests is a good idea, but it will only get you so far if individual files are ginormous.

Applications don't typically read 1GB files from a database table. Normally, application performance improves by batching commands and processing multiple items at once. With such large files, batching will quickly eat up memory so you should try adjusting your settings to process things row-by-row as much as possible. Disable prefetch for this query. If that doesn't work, try executing multiple queries, each of which will only returns a single row.

Alternatively, perhaps you could change the way the XML is stored on the database and create XML indexes to improve query performance. I haven't used these features, but Oracle provides different ways to store and index XML, and I'd bet that one of those methods allows you to read from the XML without loading the entire thing into memory. See the [XML DB Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/toc.htm) for more information.